# When would a reference listed on the patent not be considered for determination of prior art?

Tags: novelty, examination, reference

In a US patent (re)examination, under what circumstances would a reference not be considered for the determination of prior art, when that reference is cited by the examiner, appears on the front page of the granted patents, with mention of a date earlier than the earliest provisional application?

---

Case in point: in the re-examination of US patent application 09/694,416 (patent [US RE40530E1](https://patents.google.com/patent/USRE40530E1)) referencing provisional application 60/033,271 filed on Dec. 9, 1996, the examiner cited

> Captain Nemo, RSA Moduli Should Have 3 Prime factors, Aug. 1996

That's listed in the "non patent documents" section of a "Notice of References Cited" filed as "List of references cited by examiner" dated 2002-06-21 in the full records. Perhaps importantly, there is no mention for "Publisher, Edition or Volume".

My assessment of the [text of the reference](http://fgrieu.free.fr/CaptainNemo.pdf) is that it unambiguously discloses everything in claim 1 and 2 of [US 5,848,159](https://image-ppubs.uspto.gov/dirsearch-public/print/downloadPdf/5848159), and claim 1 of [US 7,231,040](https://image-ppubs.uspto.gov/dirsearch-public/print/downloadPdf/7231040), that was not well-established practice by the early 1990s. So my working hypothesis is that somewhat, this reference was taken out of the reasoning about novelty.

From the content, that reference was written circa Feb. 1996, typeset as for submission to a cryptographic conference with proceedings in the [Lecture Notes in Computers Science series](https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs), which is mentioned by initials. But so far I have been unable to locate that article either by title, author name (which clearly is a pseudonym), keyword, or other mean, in the index of these or other publications. Perhaps the article was not submitted, or rejected, and never got published. But then I wonder how it got cited as reference!

Update: meanwhile, some [detective work](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/226651?noredirect=1) uncovered that Captain Nemo is [Richard Schroeppel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Schroeppel).

Comment: I would hope the examiner could provide proof the document was actually publicly disclosed. Just because the examiner has a copy doesn't prove that.

Comment: Have you read all the back and forth between the examiner and the applicant in the record ? It may have been used in a rejection and overcome by an argument about date of publication or whether or not it was published at all.  In another question you mentioned that it is famous for being impossible to find. If it’s withdraw as established prior art I guess it could stay in the list of cited references if it was cited and successfully disputed to qualify.

Comment: @George White: I combed the full record, but found no mention of that reference X, and in fact no reasoning of the examiner. Perhaps I missed it so far, or the exchanges have been oral, or are not included for some reason. I do have the [petitioner's arguments](https://register.epo.org/application?documentId=EO2X4L615911FI4&number=EP97953075&lng=en&npl=false) in the European procedure (the meat on page 2). My assessment is they make sense against the anteriorities they repel (and the patent was accordingly granted), but not against Captain Nemo's, which is not in the EU procedure.

Comment: The examiner lists all things that seemed generally relevant that surfaced in their search. Only references that are cited in a rejection are discussed.  A listed reference may become part of a second or third rejection if claim amendments are made or if applicant arguments to earlier rejections are persuasive.